# Big-O of polynomial function (n^2+3nlogn+10^2logn+7626n+1)

Tags: data-structures, big-o

can anyone tell me the Big-O of polynomial function (n^2+3nlogn+10^2logn+7626n+1)

Comment: Your question is valid, but maybe you got downvotes because you did not say the efforts you made to solve it

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Your question does seem valid, but the way it is asked makes it very hard to find for people with a similar question. Maybe you can rephrase it by making the title more generic, (i.e. specific to your type of problem), and putting the actual function inside?

Answer (score 2):

I think is n^2 because 2^n > n^2 > n > logn > Constant level

Comment: Indeed. Based on the math theory described at https://web.mit.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf it is O(n^2).